# AirshipServiceExtension not found in SPM

Tags: swift-package-manager, urbanairship.com

I can't find the `AirshipServiceExtension` after adding `AirShip` SPM (version 17.7.1) and by using `import AirshipServiceExtension` will get

> No such module 'AirshipServiceExtension'

but don't have such issue if using CocoaPod! Can someone help me if I did something wrong?

Comment: OOC did you manage to solve this? I am facing same issue. Check here https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/1axuw8x/spm_dependency_not_found_although_i_have_added_it/

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos no but u can upvote the question maybe someone else have the answer

Comment: I solved mine, I explain it here: https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-package-libraries-always-results-in-no-such-module-when-imported/70307